# repeated measures anova's normality assumption

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, normality-assumption

I am trying to apply normality test to an experiment data, where 4 data points were acquired per person. The data looks like:

> subject name | toy | car | giraffe | cat

> Jack         10 | 11 | 9 | 8

> ...

I am required to check for assumptions of repeated measure ANOVA are satisfied. So, what are the details of this normality requirement - should all the data points be cumulatively used to check for normality or does all 4 data points should be treated as different groups and normality tests are applied to each of them separately and if normality assumption is broken even for one group, does it invalidate the ANOVA?

Comment: The assumptions are about the residuals. You should start by fitting your model and then looking at a qqplot of the residuals.

Comment: What do numbers count? Does it mean Jack has 11 cars, 9 giraffes, and 8 cats? Busy guy. // What do you want to know? Do you have a null hypothesis to test? and an alternative?

Comment: @BruceET numbers are (made up) times the subject took to recognize each item.